# Flutter - Stateful Widget Doesn't Save Counter State When Switching Tabs

Tags: dart, flutter, stateful, statefulwidget

I am learning flutter and I am working with tabBars and I am having an issue with saving the state.  I have put a small working example of my issue below.  Basically, there is a button and a stateful counter.  When I click the button, I see the text field update correctly. But, when I switch to a different tab and come back, the text field is back to zero.

I have found if i move the following line outside of _CounterState so its defined at the top level of the file, then, it works correctly.  When I switch tabs, the counter stays at the correct count when I switch back

```
int _counter = 0;
```

I don't feel like this is the appropriate way to do this and all of the examples I have seen have the variable inside of the class.  Can anyone give me any insights?  Why would it reset if it is inside the class?  Am I supposed to keep it outside the class?  Below is the simplified full example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: new Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new Counter(),
              new Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              new Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => new _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _increment,
          child: new Text('Increment'),
        ),
        new Text('Count: $_counter'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the example with the counter moved outside of the class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: new Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new Counter(),
              new Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              new Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => new _CounterState();
}

int _counter = 0; //<-- MOVED OUTSIDE THE _CounterState CLASS
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {


  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _increment,
          child: new Text('Increment'),
        ),
        new Text('Count: $_counter'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: Default Tab Bar Controller does not maintain state after swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979157/flutter-default-tab-bar-controller-does-not-maintain-state-after-swipe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As `_CounterState` widget is built everytime you go to the given TabView you'll need to put `_counter` variable in the state configuration class (`Counter`).

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  int _counter = 0;
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => new _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      widget._counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _increment,
          child: new Text('Increment'),
        ),
        new Text('Count: ${widget._counter}'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that I typically see examples with the variables in the _CounterState widget.  How did you know that you had to use `widget` before the counter as in `widget._counter++`?  I don't think I would have known that.

Comment: When accessing variables from the state controlling class you use the `widget` variable.

Comment: wow! saved my day... but as a side note, now `StatefulWidget` class marked as immutable so it's better you don't  define a not final variable in it

Answer (score 5):

As I used one solution `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

You need to use this **mixin** with your state class of **StateFullWidget**.

you need to pass **true** to **wantKeepAlive** getter method.

```
class SampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleWidgetState createState() => _SampleWidgetState();
}

class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SampleWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

This will save your state and stop your widget to recreate again. I have used it with **Tabbar** and **PageView** and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

put the variable in that statefulwidget and then call it every time as "widget.variable_name"