# How to keep data on screen of an app as it is in flutter?

Tags: node.js, flutter, api

[image: Here is a video of an issue that I am facing, every time I come on the dashboard It calls an API to fetch that image, is there any way that I can keep this image here permanently because this image is going to change on daily basis?]

I am facing an issue, There is one screen where I am calling an API and getting data but when I go on any other screen to do some work and when I come back to the home screen (main screen where I am calling API) It again call for an API and I am using loader till data is getting fetched from API. So it feels frustrating when it always calls an API.

Is there any feature or anything that I can use to keep my fetched as it is until I close my app in flutter?

Here is a video of an issue that I am facing, every time I come on the dashboard It calls an API to fetch that image, is there any way that I can keep this image here permanently because this image is going to change on daily basis?

Comment: Please include your sources

Comment: yeah i have uploaded now.

Comment: you can take a look at a similar question here with solution, using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979157/flutter-default-tab-bar-controller-does-not-maintain-state-after-swipe

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared_preferences to save your data locally after API call. then you can use these data whenever you go back to the screen.

```
 Future addSharePref() async{

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

await prefs.setString('storingName', yourVarName);
}
```

Then when you open the screen again you can just call these values from shared_preferences. something like this:

```
yourVarName= preferences.getString('storingName')?? "No name found";
```